# Installing PyODBC using pip

Tags: pip, installation, spyder, pyodbc

Newbie here.  I am trying to install PyODBC and don't quite understand how to use pip.

I downloaded PyODBC and dragged the master file into my directory.  I opened Spyder (Python 3.6), which should have pip installed.  I then typed "pip install pyodbc" into Spyder's console and got the following error:

> pip install pyodbc
>             ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I know I'm doing something wrong but can't find any good step-by-step instructions for installing packages in Spyder.  Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

`pip` is an operating system's command. Run it in an OS terminal (command window), not at Python command prompt.

And, BTW, you don't need to download packages in advance — pip itself downloads them from https://pypi.python.org/pypi .